# throttle redux-saga based on action content

Tags: redux-saga

Let us say we have a form with two inputs. onChange, for both inputs, will trigger an side-effect in redux-saga, UPDATE, with the payload name/id (input1/input2) and value. To avoid to many calls I throttle the call like this:

```
yield throttle(500, UPDATE, update)
```

This works fine. However, if I am really fast, I can type in the first input, hit tab and start typing in the second input. The last action to be dispatched will contain the name/id and value of the second input, hence missing out on all, but the first, changes to the first input.

Would it be possible to filter the throttle based on the name/id in the payload? So sagas will keep two throttle buffers for input1 and input2?

(I could get around this be dispatching another save action on onBlur, but I rather not do that.)

Answer (score 0):

I’ll suggest to keep redux-saga away from the throttling. Both inputs are probably in the same component. Why not throttle a function in the component and inside that function you dispatch the action.